# Only allow Apache 2.4 directory access from php script only- How?

Tags: php, windows, webserver, apache2.4

I have a Windows Apache Webserver that has a mapped drive to my Linux imaging server.  The Linux imaging has a directory that stores pdf files in a certain directory that we access via a PHP script. In my httpd.conf file we have an alias setup that allow access to this directory using the `Require All granted`.  Well the problem is we recently discovered that if a person knows the name of the document, they can just enter our `domain.com/<directory>/nameofdocument.pdf` in a web browser and get access to the pdf documents on our imaging server.  Granted they would have to know the exact name of the file including what directory it's stored in to bring up the pdf file.  This is a security flaw that we would like to not allow.  I don't want a person being able to enter our server address in the address bar and pull up a document that way.  Our php script accesses the directory and the user is able to click on links to pull up the document.

In other words, I only want to be able to allow a person to view the pdf if they are logged into our agency system (which is a php written system) and they access via our imaging php script.  Is this possible?

This is what my `<directory>` directive looks like.

```
Alias /ourdocs/ "Z:/documents/"
<Directory "Z:/documents">
    Options none
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Put the folder outside the website, with no directory configuration in Apache for it. Then have a `getDocument.php`  script, which, when passed suitable document ID (e.g. maybe you have the stored docs listed in your database?), first checks that the user has a valid login session, and then, if so, outputs the file to the client-side using readFile() (and setting suitable headers of course so it comes up as a download). That way the only access to the files is via a script which validates your status first. Direct links would not work since there's no direct HTTP route to the file itself.

Comment: Great comment.  This was the pretty much spot on what I was thinking.  From this comment I was able to create a new "viewdoc.php" script that will grab the pdf document from our imaging server and display that document in a popup window.  I can now remove that alias from my Apache server configuration file and that directory will no longer be viewable to my web server our the outside world.  It will only be assessable from within our  agency management system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the documents folder outside the website, with no directory configuration in Apache for it. Then have a `getDocument.php` script, which, when passed suitable document ID (e.g. maybe you have the stored docs listed in your database?), first checks that the user has a valid login session, and then, if so, outputs the file to the client-side using `readFile()` (and setting suitable headers of course so it comes up as a download).

That way the only access to the files is via a script which validates your status first. Direct links would not work since there's no direct HTTP route to the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

For blocking "externals" to access files or directoryes, you can use a modification of the directive you shown

```
<Directory "Z:/documents">
  Require local
  Require ip 172.16.0.10
  Require ip 192.168.1.0/24
  Require all denied
</Directory>
```

In this example, only "localhost" (the webserver itself), the machine with ip 172.16.0.10 and any machine in the subnet 192.168.1.0/24 can access directly this directory through the web.
EDIT, due to (unnecessary?) insight into the php side

Now, directory access is disabled for all but the written ip's. In order to download the file, on the page where you currently have the direct link to the file (eg: `<a href="domain.com/<directory>/nameofdocument.pdf">`), you will need to replace it with something like
`<a href="domain.com/fileManager.php?fileId=32">`
32 of course is for example the id of the file within your table which stores the data of the available files.
In your fileManager.php page you will then need to have something like this

```
// Other stuffs
....
// Check if the user is logged in
$logged_in = $this->isLoggedIn();
if ($logged_in) {
    // Ok, the user is logged in
    // Go to retrieve the path for the requested file id
    $file = $this->docDb->findDocument( intval( $_GET [ "fileId" ] ) );
    // Does the file exists?
    if (file_exists( $file )) {
        // Here we are, the file exists. Force the download
        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
        header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename( $file ) . '"' );
        header('Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
        header( 'Pragma: public' );
        header( 'Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file ) );
        readfile( $file );
        // Exit or do other things, it depends on your purpose after downloading the file
        exit();
    } else {
        // Nope, the file doesn't exists
        $this->error( "Sorry, the requested file does not seem to exist" );
    }
} else {
    // Nope, the user isn't logged in
    $this->error( "Sorry, you're not authorized to download the file" );
}
// Other stuffs
....
```

Comment: This won't do the job, because requests for documents from end-users will still come from their browser, and thus from their own IP address. Therefore will just block _all_ requests for the files from the end-users, since the OP states they are accessing them directly via hyperlinks. To make it work, the OP would need to then replace the hyperlinks in the app with a PHP script which accesses the files itself. But at that point you might as well just remove the "Directory" entry from the config entirely so the folder isn't on the web at all - as per my comment under the question.

Comment: Also the requirement in the question was to be able to check the user's logged-in status before granting access to the document. All your suggestion does is simply block access to the documents...it doesn't take any steps towards providing an authentication mechanism.

Comment: Sorry no!
This DO the job. He wants only auth user can access and this MUST be done by their app, not by the server. "Our php script accesses the directory and the user is able to click on links to pull up the document"
So there is a link to be clicked and this is about 4 lines of php code to download the pdf and the user said "stores pdf files in a certain directory that we access via a PHP script"
That's definetly one of the right solution, as of "take off the root document directory"

Comment: I cannot comment on @ADyson answer but that solution can cause problems! If you keep the directory OUT of the webServer and out of the document root, there are possibilities that you cannot access at all the directory and the files inside.
If not declared at least as alias and so "unknow" to the server, you cannot access if you have a "per user" root directory for the server or some other kind of restrictions.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html

Comment: `there are possibilities that you cannot access at all the directory and the files inside`...in what scenario exactly? That would only be if PHP is incorrectly configured not to be able to access the folder on disk - and that is easy to fix. `you cannot access if you have a "per user" root directory for the server `...most accounts of this type have a `public_html` folder (or similar) which is open to the web, but the account will have a folder level above that where other subfolders can be created, to hold useful things like config files, data storage etc which should not be public.

Comment: `"Our php script accesses the directory and the user is able to click on links to pull up the document" So there is a link to be clicked and this is about 4 lines of php code to download the pdf`...but the OP doesn't have that code. Their app pulls up a direct hyperlink to the document - e.g. `https://example.com/documents.doc1.pdf`. That is not controlled or authorised by a PHP script. If we follow your idea, then the user will simply be blocked from accessing it at any time, because when they click that link the request comes from their IP and browser, not from the PHP server.

Comment: Your approach does _nothing_ to implement the authentication, unlike my answer which describes in detail what to do. All your code does is block the access, it doesn't take the next step.

Comment: open_basedir in php, for example, can be a security measure one would not bypass, so having a dir outside webroot and outside open_basedir can block any request, even through php. It all depends on how you configure BOTH apache and Php. One can be right on Apache but have restrictions on Php or viceversa

Comment: `but the OP doesn't have that code`
Who says that? The OP says exactly the opposite: "if they are logged into our agency system (which is a php written system) and are logging in via our imaging php script" then it is reasonable to think that there is scripts/functions/classes for checking if the user is logged in and the OP explicitly asks about the apache directives, so much so that he posts his implementation.
If he wanted some ideas for php side protection he would have asked for scripting, with snippets of code, not with a directive for apache.

Comment: Absoutely, open_basedir can cause issues, but all the OP needs to do is configure it to their needs and there would be no issue.

Comment: `it is reasonable to think that there is scripts/functions/classes for checking if the user is logged in`....I didn't say they didn't have this. I think you misunderstood me. I said that because they are printing direct hyperlinks to the documents into the web page, any such script cannot be used to provide the necessary security. Hence why my suggested solution is to entirely remove the documents from the web root, instead write a "getDocuments" PHP script which can 1) employ the security checks, and then 2) if checks are successful, use PHP to fetch and output the document content.

Comment: As far as I can see, your proposed solution only involved preventing access to the documents folder, it does not extend to providing the replacement functionality. And I think the OP's comment on the main thread above, in response to mine, shows that that "getDocuments" type of script is not functionality that they already had available. They had an authentication mechanism, but the solution involves combining that with code which fetches the documents from the hidden folder, and outputting them

Comment: `your proposed solution was just to prevent access to the documents folder` of course! If OP has a script that prints the link, it's extremely easy to change it so that it can for example print a link to another function in the same php "page", function that checks if one is logged in and then, with the "4 lines of code" displays/downloads, through the php "headers" functions, the content of the Pdf. Again, If he wanted some ideas for php side protection he would have asked for scripting, with snippets of code, not with a directive for apache

Comment: `If OP has a script that prints the link, it's extremely easy to change it so that it can for example print a link to another function in the same php "page", function that checks if one is logged in and then, with the "4 lines of code" displays/downloads, through the php "headers" functions, the content of the Pdf.`...I agree, that's why I suggested doing it. But your answer doesn't suggest doing that.

Comment: `Again, If he wanted some ideas for php side protection he would have asked for scripting, with snippets of code, not with a directive for apache`...people don't always know what the solution is. They sometimes ask for what they _think_ the solution is, but that isn't always actually how it can be solved.

Comment: But actually, I don't see where they specifically asked for a solution involving only an Apache directive? The actual stated requirement is: `I only want to be able to allow a person to view the pdf if they are logged into our agency system (which is a php written system) and they access via our imaging php script.`. That (sensibly) doesn't specify how the requirement should be implemented.

Comment: Hemm...@ADyson ... the title of the question!!!! **Only allow Apache 2.4 directory access from php script only- How?**
It's clear, I suppose, it's an Apache related question, don't you think?

Comment: The title is just badly worded. Apache doesn't control access to the directory when the accessing is done by the PHP script - because PHP accesses the directory via filesystem commands, not via HTTP requests through Apache. So the title is misleading, that's all, and what it's asking for is effectively impossible, logically. Just remove the "Apache 2.4" from that sentence and it would be a more meaningful title. Also, you're taking the title out of context from the rest of the question, which gives a better and more detailed explanation of the real requirement.

Comment: getting boring! If one cannot access a file via http, that's the goal of accessing a file only trough script....and deny access via http is done via apache (mainly, of course)

Comment: `getting`...maybe stop making pedantic / spurious objections then :-). The simple fact is this: The OP, as clearly stated in the question, wants only authenticated users to be able to access the image files. If the OP implemented _only_ the code you've provided in this answer, then the result would be that _nobody_ could access the images, whether they are authenticated or not. Therefore, your solution doesn't fully solve the problem or meet the requirements. I've explained this several times in different ways on this thread now.

Comment: There needs to be an additional piece of functionality added which consists of a PHP script which can fetch the documents based on an ID, having first used PHP to check the user's authentication status. The OP has already stated, in the comments above, that this was what they needed, and that it has solved their problem. Your answer does not suggest that extra functionality, therefore it does not meet the requirement in the question. It's very simple really and there's nothing more to say. You are, of course, free to either edit your answer or delete it :-). Have a good day

Comment: That is 10,000 times better. Thanks.

Comment: @DanieleContinenza the second part of your answer with the filemanager.php script was pretty much my solution.  It's basically what I did with just a few minor differences.  For the most part thanks for your comments and help.  You guys helped me solve a major security flaw in our Agency Management System.